# Cant display color images in navigation menu with theme set as DarkActionBar

Tags: android, styles, navigation-drawer

I have set DarkActionBar as the theme of my app. With this theme i am not able to display images like jpg or png in navigation menu. I am only able to display the vector graphics in black or white. Any colored image is replaced with a dark rectangle. Does any one has an idea what must be changed in this theme to get the color images display in navigation menu. Below is the style which i am applying.

> style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
</style>

<style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">-1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.2</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

> The xml code of my item is as under

```
<item android:title="Regional">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/language"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_language_black_24dp"
            android:title="Set Language" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

I have spent a lot of time without but not able to solve the issue. Expecting any kind of help or suggestions!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 yournavigationview.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

that should disable the default tinting